# How can I reset an Xubuntu session?

Tags: xubuntu, xfce, autostart, session

Everytime time I boot and login into my Xubuntu 14.10, Skype, Thunderbird and Firefox start up even though I closed them before I logged out and shut down. These programs are *not* in the list of autostart programs. So how can I reset the session?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem in Xfce as well where goldendict kept opening on startup. In order to solve this, you go to session and startup on settings and go to the application autostart tab. Then go to add, and make the name and description whatever you would like. Under command put killall (program name). Add this for whatever programs you don't want on startup. Also, under general, you may want to uncheck the Automatically save session on logout. Under the session tab you may want to clear saved sessions.

Comment: The hint "Under the session tab you may want to clear saved sessions" did the trick!